Is it rational to try avoiding being a free-rider?
Me (A) and my friend (B) often have debates on various topics that go like this:

A does an action that has a negligible effect by itself but ultimately contributes to a common good.
B: If what you do is negligible, that means you could stop doing it and virtually nothing would change. It's irrational for you to continue doing it, save your resources for something more impactful.
A: I agree that my individual action is a droplet in the ocean, but if everybody in the world follows your advice, then "virtually nothing would change" would stop being true.
B: You can't generalize like that, nobody else is affected by your decision to stop doing it. Your integrity is compromised if your belief is that this action results in more good if more people do it, but your lack of integrity doesn't hurt this "common good", as long as you aren't using it (the integrity) as currency when convincing others.

At this point, when I notice the pattern, I simply stop the debate, because I disagree that "it's a waste of time", but am unable to put my intuition into words, or even fully understand why I feel the way I feel about it.
My attempt at rationalization
All "common good" problems I can currently think of are best solved through legislation. But if any of such laws were to be passed right now, even with a reasonable plan that doesn't destroy the economy or society, there would be riots. Laws are more or less just code for "what's popular", so it's not surprising.
That means awareness needs to be spread first. It can and should be done in multiple ways, but one of them is leading by example and trying out the limits imposed by a potential law on yourself. By doing that, you develop habits and prepare for the future, you signal your preferences to businesses and authorities in one way or another, you expose people in your life to the problem you believe they should be giving more attention to.
My questions
Does the above ever add up to anything? I'm sure there are modern philosophers who tackle this (I guess collective action problem?), what are their conclusions and proposed solutions? Does the chance of success (e.g., passing a law) go down if everybody free-rides and contributes only by having an opinion and being vocal about it? If it does, how is free-riding discouraged? Is it always some form of manipulation, like marketing, or have there been instances where the "game theory" aspect of it is explained to large audiences and they react favorably and act?
Also, could non-free-riders be described as collectively productive but individually fanatic fools?
This is a long chain of questions, and incomplete, but I hope it helps understand better what I'm curious about. Any additional detail is highly welcome. My wish is to get to the bottom of it and either concede and revise my approach to life, or learn to defend my position without resorting to deontology.
An example
Common good: Environment (global warming).
Law: Universal carbon tax.
Action: Watch electricity consumption despite being able to afford care-free use of it, don't fly for leisure, eat low-emission foods, avoid disposable packaging, consume less, etc.

It's not always true that "wasting your time" is valid reasoning. Suppose it takes the same time and effort to do X as it does to do Y, but X contributes to the 'good' cause and Y contributes to the 'bad' cause. It's a matter of attitude, not of time and effort, and it seems that some people think one of the two options "costs them". Perhaps it costs them credibility in their peer group.

Not sure if I'm understanding your comment correctly, but if you're saying "it's better to spend resources contributing to a hypothetical common good than something that's less good overall", then both me and my friend would agree with that. The nuance though is that there's a high opportunity cost here. Extreme example: I commit to not fly for leisure (noticeable impact for me), but it's -1 person flown out of 10 million every day (immeasurable).

I am saying that some people find reasons for not doing something for the common good, even when it's not more 'expensive' to do so.


"All "common good" problems are best solved through legislation. But if any of such laws were to be passed right now, even with a reasonable plan that doesn't destroy the economy or society, there would be riots." ==[ Ballocks! Ballocks, I say! You tried to slip that outrageous assumption in unnoticed. There are laws against crapping in the park. But if you can sneak in and do it at night, your toilet-flush water bill will be less. That law could only cause riots if trump got caught doing it.


Yes, on Kantian conception of rationality, at least, which implies the categorical imperative:"Act only according to that maxim whereby you can at the same time will that it should become a universal law." Egoistic 'rationality' is well-known to lead to catastrophic outcomes known as the tragedy of the commons. B's second response is invalid b/c it does not matter whether others are affected by your decision. They are affected by incentives to keep doing it, and that is reason enough to stop given the effects of everybody doing it.
